# Issues with xlim and ylim in boarders() and inserting text with geom_text() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following is my R code:

```
library("ggplot2")

xlon <- c(11.9, 156.6) # deg. E
ylat <- c(78.9, 71.3)  # deg. N

#Using GGPLOT, plot the Base World Map
mp <- NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="black", ylim=c(40, 90), xlim=c(0, 200), 
                    col="white",exact=TRUE, fill="gray100") # create a layer of borders
mp <- ggplot() + mapWorld

#Now Layer the cities on top
mp <- mp+ geom_point(aes(x=xlon, y=ylat) ,color="blue", size=3)
mp
```

The purpose of my code is to plot a world map with grid box bounding the exact region of 40-90 deg. N and 0-200 deg E. When I run the above code, I find that y limits range from 20 to 90 deg. N while the limits of x seems to start before 0 deg E. Can anyone suggest me how to get the exact boundaries in x- and y- directions as specified?

Further, I wanted to include the location label for the two points on the map. The two points are:

Barrow: 71.3N, 156.6 E
Ny-Ålesund: 78.9 N, 11.9 E

Can anyone help me in the code on how to include the "Barrow" and "Ny-Ålesund" besides the points? I tried geom_text(), but could not succeed.

Answer (score 2):

For adding the text you can try the following:

```
df <- data.frame(lat=c(71.3, 78.9), lon=c(156.6, 11.9), label=c('Barrow', 'Ny-Ålesund'))
mp + geom_text(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = label), 
               size = 5, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)
```

[image]

Try this to limit x and y axis:

```
df <- data.frame(lat=c(71.3, 78.9), lon=c(156.6, 11.9), label=c('Barrow', 'Ny-Ålesund'))
mp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=lon, y=ylat)) + mapWorld + 
  xlim(0, 200) + ylim(40, 90)
mp + geom_point(aes(x=xlon, y=ylat) ,color="blue", size=3) +
  geom_text( aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = label), 
               size = 5, vjust = 1, hjust = 0.75, col='red')
```

[image]

Try this for circular projection (you can change the orientation to get the best one):

```
mp + geom_point(aes(x=xlon, y=ylat) ,color="blue", size=5) +
  geom_text( aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = label), 
               size = 5, vjust = 1, hjust = 0.75, col='red') + coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(25, 25, 0)) # for ortho maps
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works!!! 

May I know why the axes limits are not maintained in the plot?

Comment: Thanks and it works!! I have one more question ... Can you please also suggest me how I try this map with different map projections? I want the map to have a circular type representation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the code as below:

`df <- data.frame(lat=c(71.3, 78.9), lon=c(156.6, 11.9), label=c('Barrow', 'Ny-Ålesund'))
mp <- NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="black",col="white", fill="gray100") 
mp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=lon, y=ylat)) + mapWorld + xlim(0, 200) + ylim(40, 90)+ geom_point(aes(x=c(11.9, 156.6), y=c(78.9, 71.3)) ,color="blue", size=3) +geom_text( aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = label), size = 3, vjust = 1, hjust = 0.75, col='red') + coord_map("azequalarea", orientation=c(90,0,360))`

Comment: If you run the code by replacing the 'coord_map("azequalarea", orientation=c(90,0,360))' in your code, then I still do not get the required figure. The xlabels and y-labels are still appearing. I want these labels on the circular and line grids.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the script:

```
library("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(lat=c(71.3, 78.9), lon=c(156.6, 11.9), label=c('Barrow', 'Ny-Ålesund'))
mp <- NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="black",col="white", fill="gray100") # create a layer of borders
mp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=lon, y=lat)) + mapWorld + xlim(0, 360) + ylim(40, 90)+ 
  geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat) ,color="blue", size=2.5) +
  geom_text( aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = label), 
             size=3,vjust=1,hjust=0.75,col='red') + 
  coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(90,90,0))
mp
```

[This is the resulting figure from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f4Kg.png)

But I require a figure of the following type:
[Required figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AeSf.png)

How can I change my above code to get the requisite projection or orientation?